# Prevent CreateFileMapping from altering source file (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, file-mapping

I'm studying Memory Mapping on Windows and wrote the following piece code (I omitted error handling from the copy for the sake of readability):

```
HANDLE file_h = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

HANDLE map_h = CreateFileMapping(file_h, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, lengthOfFile + padding, NULL);

char * map;
map = MapViewOfFile(map_h, FILE_MAP_COPY, 0, 0, lengthOfFile + padding);
```

Where *lengthOfFile* is the length of the file I previously calculated this way (for some reasons that are unrelevant to this case):

```
FILE * file;
file = fopen(filename,"rb");
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int lengthOfFile = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
int last = (lengthOfFile % 4);
int n_pack = (int)(lengthOfFile / 4);
int padding = 4 - last;
```

And *padding* is some additional length I needed to add (you may figure out why by reading the code above).

After that, I perform some operations with the memory mapped file which involve its modification and the dispatch of its new value to another function.

How can I make it so that when I close both the *file_h* and *map_h* handles the source file (filename) stays **unaltered** (right now, as soon as I close its handle it gets modified because of that additional *padding* which apparently gets "flushed" to the source file right after its handle is closed) ?

I tried using the *PAGE_WRITECOPY* flag alongside the *PAGE_READWRITE* (which is needed to modify the content of the memory mapped file) one, but the *CreateFileMapping* function fails returning a *ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER* (87) error.

In other words, I need to achieve the same behavior I managed to get in Unix using:
`mmap(0,lengthOfFile + padding,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, **MAP_PRIVATE**,fileno(file),0);`

I guess the key point is the *MAP_PRIVATE* attribute.

Comment: There is no equivalent of that flag.  A basic workaround is to pass INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as the first argument so the memory is backed by the paging file and can't update the actual file.  You'll have to fread() the file into the view yourself.

Comment: Is there really no other way to prevent the modification of the source file in Windows? It's not important if I don't get the exactly same result as I get with MAP_PRIVATE.

Comment: Perhaps try `FILE_MAP_COPY` (alone) with **`PAGE_WRITECOPY`**? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018806/copy-on-write-file-mapping-on-windows#comment96793206_55018806