# Copy-on-write file mapping on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files, copy-on-write

I have 3 processes communicating over named pipes: server, writer, reader. The basic idea is that the *writer* can store huge (~GB) binary blobs on the *server*, and the *reader(s)* can retrieve it. But instead of sending data on the named pipe, memory mapping is used.

The *server* creates an unnamed file-backed mapping with `CreateFileMapping` with `PAGE_READWRITE` protection, then duplicates the handle into the *writer*. After the *writer* has done its job, the handle is duplicated into any number of interested *readers*.

The *writer* maps the handle with `MapViewOfFile` in `FILE_MAP_WRITE` mode.

The *reader* maps the handle with `MapViewOfFile` in `FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_COPY` mode.

On the *reader* I want copy-on-write semantics, so as long the mapping is only read it is shared between all reader instances. But if a reader wants to write into it (eg. in-place parsing or image processing), the impacts should be limited to the modifying process with the least number of copied pages possible.

**The problem**
When the *reader* tries to write into the mapping it dies with segmentation fault as if `FILE_MAP_COPY` was not considered.
What's wrong with the above described method? According to MSDN this should work...

We have the same mechanism implemented on linux as well (with `mmap` and fd passing in AF_UNIX ancillary buffers) and it works as expected.

Comment: you must use `FILE_MAP_COPY` only instead `FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_COPY`

Comment: The way I read it is, COPY is just a flag that can be combined with the access mode. Since you do intend to write to the address you should use WRITE and since you also want CoW you should ask for WRITE|COPY.

Comment: @Anders - you mean use `FILE_MAP_COPY|FILE_MAP_WRITE` ? if you try this - can view that this combination of flags converted to `PAGE_READWRITE`. only single `FILE_MAP_COPY` converted to `PAGE_WRITECOPY`. as is. if want - test code https://pastebin.com/LkTj72Cd

Comment: @RbMm, using `FILE_MAP_COPY` indeed solved the issue. And yeah, the documentation page is misleading (bitwise-OR comment) on this flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

problem here that [`MapViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) bad designed or/and documented. this is shell (with restricted functionality) over [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection). the *dwDesiredAccess* parameter of [`MapViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) converted to *Win32Protect* parameter of [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection).

the `FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_COPY` combination converted to `PAGE_READONLY` page protection, because this you and get page fault on write.

you need use `FILE_MAP_COPY` only flag - it converted to `PAGE_WRITECOPY` page protection  and in this case all will be work.

the best solution of course direct use [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) with `PAGE_WRITECOPY` page protection

Comment: Using the NT API when Win32 can be made to work is never the best solution IMHO.

Comment: @Anders Isn't the point that the Win32 API cannot be made to do what is desired in this case?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no, `MapViewOfFile` with single flag `FILE_MAP_COPY` do job correct and as desired. but for me unclear logic under flag conversion. the `ZwMapViewOfSection` have more clear design

Answer (score 4):

TL:DR: RbMm is correct, you must pass **just** `FILE_MAP_COPY` to `MapViewOfFile` to get copy-on-write behavior.

The current Microsoft documentation is incorrect, it incorrectly states that `FILE_MAP_COPY` can be OR'ed with `FILE_MAP_<ALL_ACCESS|READ|WRITE>`.

Looking at older versions of MSDN [it correctly says](http://web.archive.org/web/20021222022224/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/fileio/base/mapviewoffile.asp) that you must choose one of the access modes:

> Type of access to the file view and, therefore, the protection of the pages mapped by the file. This parameter can be **one of the following values**.
>
> - FILE_MAP_WRITE
> - FILE_MAP_READ
> - FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS
> - FILE_MAP_COPY

No longer relevant but still surprising, on Windows 95/98/ME the copy-on-write behavior only applies to the file, writes **are** propagated to views in other processes!